# Extract Keyfile JSON from saved connection of type "google_cloud_platform"

Tags: python, airflow

I have saved a connection of type "google_cloud_platform" in Airflow as described here https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections

Now in my DAG, I need to extract from the saved connection the Keyfile JSON

What is the correct hook to be used?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_api_base_hook.GoogleCloudBaseHook`](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook/index.html#airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_api_base_hook.GoogleCloudBaseHook) to get the stored connection. For example

```py
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_api_base_hook import GoogleCloudBaseHook

gcp_hook = GoogleCloudBaseHook(gcp_conn_id="<your-conn-id>")
keyfile_dict = gcp_hook._get_field('keyfile_dict')
```

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions no longer work. Here's a way that's working in 2023:

```py
from airflow.models import Connection

conn = Connection.get_connection_from_secrets(
    conn_id='my-gcp-connection'
)

json_key = conn.extra_dejson['keyfile_dict']

with open('gcp_svc_acc.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_key)
```

Mostly because the imports moved around I think.

The question specifically refers to keyfile JSON, but this is a quick addendum for those who configured keyfile path instead: take care to check if it's `keyfile_dict` OR `keyfile_path` that the Airflow admin configured, as they're two different ways to set up the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `BaseHook` as follows:

```py
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

GCP_CONNECTION_ID="my-gcp-connection"
BaseHook.get_connection(GCP_CONNECTION_ID).extras["extra__google_cloud_platform__keyfile_dict"]
```